# Is there any way in Python to index a text (as a string?) by recording each character's location?

Tags: python, arrays, string, indexing

Is it possible to take a long text such as a story or novel or news article and "index" each individual character in the text?

For example, let's take the following sentence:

The acidic clouds slowly moved over the city, blanketing it with a fog that began to choke the life from its residents.

In the above sentence, the first (or zero) character is t, the second and third, h and e. As the text continues, there will be dozens and eventually hundreds of instances of t, h, e, and every other letter of the alphabet, as well as punctuation marks, etc.

Is is possible to create an index of these, where, for example, a string would exist that indexes all the instances of e? Maybe it would look something like, 3, 17, 23, 29, 33, 45, 51, 59, 123, 4334, etc. After the entire text has been indexed (and "divided up" via character), these indexes will then be accessible via searching, so the numbers (character locations) can be referenced and, when necessary, converted back into a character. Is this possible? Sorry if any of the above isn't clear.

Comment: Yes, it's possible: create a dict-of-lists, where the dict keys are letters and the dict values are lists of indexes.

Comment: Look up Enumerate.

Comment: It's for a crypt0 app project, for generating randomness from texts of various sorts, such as literature, etc., and then using these one time only, so as to avoid any repeats in positions.

Comment: So basically the "key" will be this original block of text...once these indexes are created, each position will be linked to a specific character. Without the original text the position will mean nothing. When creating the ciphertext from the original text(plaintext) and indexed positions, positions will be chosen at random from the indexes and used to build the ciphertext. So, for example, there may be 317 instances of e in the original plaintext, and in the ciphertext there will be 317 different numbers, each of which points to a separate instance of e in the key.

Comment: I think I will need to submit a different question in regards to the random selection process.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.

```
def get_indices(text):
    if text is None:
        return None
    indices = {}
    for i in range(len(text)):
        char = text[i]
        try:
            indices[char].append(i)
        except KeyError:
            indices[char] = [i]
    return indices
```

or alternately (as suggested):

```
import collections

def get_indices_2(text):
    if text is None:
        return None
    indices = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i, char in enumerate(text):
        indices[char].append(i)
    return indices
```

That should work for mapping characters to positions.

Comment: use a `defaultdict`. or `setdefault` method of plain `dict`. And you should probably use `enumerate`.

Comment: Okay, the above is less Pythonic than not I suppose. I'll edit to include both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
s = 'The acidic clouds slowly moved over the city, blanketing it with a fog that began to choke the life from its residents.'

letter_indices = {}

for i, let in enumerate(s):
   letter_indices.setdefault(let, []).append(i)
```

Also, as suggested in comments, you can use `defaultdict` (and it is better than previous):

```
from collections import defaultdict

letter_indices = defaultdict(list)

for i, let in enumerate(s):
    letter_indices[let].append(i)
```

Comment: Curiosity: why to use `lower()` if case doesn't matter?

Comment: But if it doesn't then neither are needed.

Comment: Supposing that case matters, why would .lower() be a bad choice? @godaygo (I guess you could just use your own checks with ord() or save a reference to .lower())

Comment: This will be horribly inefficient because you are rebuilding the list of indices each time. Use a `defaultdict` with `append`. Or use `letter_indices.setdefault(let, []).append(i)`.  This will actually matter for large text.